# How to improve my query performance SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, database-performance

I have a temp table inside my procedure which joins with another temp table and it seems taking some time to run.
Could anyone suggest how to speedup this.

Below is my piece of code:

```
    declare @installs table
    (
        UserName varchar(200),
        DeviceName varchar(500),
        FirstSeenDate datetime
    )

    insert into @installs
    SELECT  [Username] 
          ,[Device Name]
          ,min([First Seen]) as 'Install Date'
      FROM [DataCollection].[dbo].[iBoss_Installed_Users]
      where [Device Type] not like '%Server%'
      group by [Device Name], Username
      

    declare @installs_User table
    (
        UserName varchar(200),
        InstalledDate varchar(max)

    )

    insert into @installs_User
    select main.UserName,
            left(main.installs,len(main.installs)-1) as "Installs"
        From
        (
        select distinct ins2.UserName,
            (
                select convert(varchar(200),ins.FirstSeenDate)+', ' as [text()]
                from @installs ins
                where ins.UserName=ins2.UserName
                order by ins.Username
                for XML PATH('')
            ) [installs]
            from @installs ins2
        )[Main]
```

Comment: can you show the tables, might be easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: For performance related questions we need an execution plan, which you can provide using "Paste The Plan".

Comment: @ Dale K
 seems like my XML PATH('') taking time.Is there any alternate for this

Comment: Is this ***really*** for SQL Server 2008?

Comment: @MatBailie ,Nope.I am using sql server 2016

Comment: "seems like my `XML PATH('')` is taking time" - what are you basing that on? You can try randomly changing things to see if the performance improves. Alternatively you can systematically investigate and find out for sure.

Comment: Please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan I'm guessing the `DISTINCT` is causing issues, as is the unnecessary table variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using a table variable or temporary table, and instead use a common table expression. I'd also use `GROUP BY` rather than `DISTINCT`, so the optimiser knows it doesn't have to try de-duplicating your list of dates...

```
declare @installs_User table
(
    UserName varchar(200),
    InstalledDate varchar(max)
);

WITH
    installs AS
(
    SELECT [Username] 
          ,[Device Name]
          ,min([First Seen]) as 'Install Date'
    FROM [DataCollection].[dbo].[iBoss_Installed_Users]
    where [Device Type] not like '%Server%'
    group by [Device Name], Username
) 
insert into
    @installs_User
SELECT main.UserName
      ,left(main.installs,len(main.installs)-1) as "Installs"
From
(
    SELECT
        ins2.UserName,
        (
            select convert(varchar(200),ins.FirstSeenDate)+', ' as [text()]
            from installs ins
            where ins.UserName=ins2.UserName
            order by ins.Username
            for XML PATH('')
        ) [installs]
    FROM
        installs ins2
    GROUP BY
        ins2.UserName
)
    [Main]
```

Comment: Hi  @matbailie .Thanks for your answer.But Seems like the approach you gave taking long time than mine

Comment: @ram : Please then respond to DaleK's comment, and include the execution plan in your question? Using this website or similar; https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ (My guess is that your source table doesn't have adequate indexing.)

Answer (score 0):

First these are not temp tables, these are table variables and SQL Server has hard coded statics for them, so estimation is always way off and they suck in that matter.

So if you just use temp table instead and (maybe add index on them) will help a lot:

```
create table #installs
    (
        UserName varchar(200),
        DeviceName varchar(500),
        FirstSeenDate datetime
    )

insert into #installs
SELECT  [Username] 
....
```